# Long delay before importing to Drupal

Tags: app, import

I'm completely new to SF. We have an app that is connected to Salesforce. The app communicates with Drupal via the Salesforce Suite module to update/insert/delete new SF contacts.

For some reason, we sometimes have a huge delay before the "import" is done. A contact created at 9 won't import until 10+, even thought the import runs every 10 minutes and we see some other contact being imported/updated.

What could be the cause of such a "lag" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few suggestions,

1. Check your connected salesforce instance status from https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/. There may be some performance issue. If that the case your direct salesforce login also should experience the same slowness.
2. Eventhough you may have tried should mention, try debug and see where the slowness is occurring(which line of code).
3. If you confident that the issue is with Salesforce suite report an issue at [Issues for Salesforce Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/salesforce).
   Found [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2295947) somewhat similar issue at the forum if it helps you (hope you aren't the person who posted this :) ).